# Almacenar en una variable la contraseña desencriptada de un usuario en WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Estoy creando una función, la cual toma los datos de un usuario que inicia sesión por primera vez y luego los datos son enviados a una URL para así registrarlos en otro sistema. La duda que tengo es como almacenar la variable de la contraseña sin encriptar y asegurarme que realmente la variable que envía la URL ($url_registro y $url_acceso) funciona.

```html
//ENVIAR DATOS DE NUEVOS USUARIOS REGISTRADOS AL SISTEMA DE ABSTRACTS EXTERNO
function shapeSpace_register_add_meta($user_id) {
 add_user_meta($user_id, '_new_user', '1');
}
add_action('user_register', 'shapeSpace_register_add_meta');

function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {
 $new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
 if ($new_user) {
  update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  $titulo = $current_user->title;
  $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname;
  $apellido = $current_user->user_lastname;
  $institucion = $current_user->institution;
  $direccion = $current_user->addr1;
  $ciudad = $current_user->city;
  $pais = $current_user->country;
  $correo = $current_user->user_email;
  $correo_anterior = $correo;
  $contrasena = $current_user->password; // ¿La contraseña está encriptada?

  if (empty($titulo)) {
    $titulo = "Mr";
  }

  if (empty($institucion)) {
    $institucion = "Unknown institution";
  }

  if (empty($ciudad)) {
    $ciudad = "Unknown city";
  }

  $url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .contrasena. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior;
  $url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$contrasena;

  echo "<form action='" .$url_registro. "' name='enviar_usuario'></form>";
  echo "<form action='" .$url_acceso. "' name='login_usuario'></form>";
  echo "<script> document.enviar_usuario.submit(); document.login_usuario.submit();</script>";

 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Es que no sé si la línea de código $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); me permite tomar la contraseña y si me lo permite ¿estaría encriptada? Por otro lado no se si las líneas de código con el "echo" funcionaran para enviar la URL en segundo plano.

Comment: Solo por curiosear un poco, ¿que motivo hay para guardar una contraseña ajena sin su _hash_?. Por otra parte, si lo he entendido bien, las `url` que forman parte del `action`del formulario ¿envían las contraseñas tal cual las introduce el usuario a través de la `url`? A mi entender deberías buscar otra forma de transferir esos datos. Y sobre la contraseña, el momento de capturarla sería en el la fase de registro, reseteo o de cambio de contraseña. `WP` ya prevé no duplicar usuarios. Si lo capturas en el `log in` vas a tener que realizar esa comprobación en cada inicio de sesión.

Comment: Ya entiendo mejor. Oscar cual es la función que sirve para capturar la contraseña sin encriptar, además puedo mover una variable de una función a otra?

Answer (score 1):

para manipular la contraseña, te conviene hacer el codigo de registro, hacer la forma en html donde ingrese o se cree la contraseña automáticamente, de ahi tomas la contraseña desencriptada.

Para registral al nuevo usuario usas el siguiente código:

```
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
        'user_login'        => $user_login,
        'user_pass'         => $user_pass,
        'user_email'        => $user_email,
        'first_name'        => $user_first,
        'last_name'         => $user_last,
        'user_registered'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    )
);
if($new_user_id) {
    add_user_meta( $new_user_id, "titulo", $current_user->title, false );
    add_user_meta( $new_user_id, "institucion", $current_user->institution, false );
    add_user_meta( $new_user_id, "direccion", $current_user->addr1, false );
    add_user_meta( $new_user_id, "ciudad", $current_user->city, false );
    add_user_meta( $new_user_id, "pais", $current_user->country, false );
}
```

Yo he creado plugin de registro en el front end usando el anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente código dentro del archivo "functions.php"

```
function register_user_add_meta($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_pass'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass_plano', $_POST['user_pass']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'register_user_add_meta');
```